# Getting untrusted proxy message while trying to setup secure NIFI cluster

Tags: security, proxy, apache-nifi

I am using nifi V-1.3, and trying to setup 3 node secure NIFI cluster.

I have added all the required properties, I can see nodes sending heartbeats in logs in all the nodes but on screen I'm getting Untrusted proxy message for all nodes. error screen shot attached.

**Error log** getting as NiFiAuthenticationFilter **Rejecting access to web api:** **Untrusted proxy CN=hostname**

could you please tell if anybody overcomes it.

Thanks.

```
  Find the nifi properties below:
<authorizer>
            <identifier>file-provider</identifier>
            <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAuthorizer</class>
            <property name="AuthorizationsFile">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
            <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
            <property name="Initial Admin Identity">Mathes@example.com</property>
            <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
            <property name="Node Identity 1">CN=node1@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
            <property name="Node Identity 2">CN=CN=node2@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
            <property name="Node Identity 3">CN=CN=node3@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
    </authorizer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and my workarround was this:

Edit nifi.properties maping so when you try to connect to nifi using a certificate it map you to the initial admin user:

```
nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.dn=^CN=(.*?), OU=(.*?)
nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.dn=<Initial Admin Identity>, OU=
```

Then you have to edit the authorizations.xml and add this line:

```
<policy identifier="nifi-cluster-write" resource="/proxy" action="W">
        <user identifier="HASH OF INITIAL ADMIN"/>
</policy>
```

Aparently the problem is that the initial admin identity does not have the "/proxy" policy.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your proxy node values may be incorrect. You have an extra `CN=` in the DN.

Change

```
<property name="Node Identity 1">CN=node1@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
<property name="Node Identity 2">CN=CN=node2@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
<property name="Node Identity 3">CN=CN=node3@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
```

to

```
<property name="Node Identity 1">CN=node1@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
<property name="Node Identity 2">CN=node2@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
<property name="Node Identity 3">CN=node3@example.com, OU=NIFI</property>
```

If you examine the complete `logs/nifi-app.log` and `logs/nifi-user.log` stacktrace output, you should be able to see the provided hostname on the connection and compare this with the actual DN of the certificates you have provided.